# ipad programming with vpn issues

Tags: ipad, vpn

Do iPad in the simulator and the Macbook share a same network? I have connect a wifi then VPN on my Macbook and everything works just fine on the outside Safari. But when I open the iPad simulator and it seems on that inside Safari the VPN is not set up yet cuz I cant access to my specified website. (But internet still works. I guess it is the wifi)

Not sure if I make it clear. I wonder how can I solve this problem. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the iOS Simulator runs with the same IP and actually in the same process space as other applications on your Mac.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. is the version of safari in simulator the same as the one on mac or dependent on IOS? I am using Websocket which requires the latest version of safari.

Comment: The OS in the simulator is basically equivalent to what will run on the device. So the Safari version in the simulator is dependent on the iOS version, not on the Safari installed in Mac OS X.